# Preventing full screen keyboard: pull up EditText so it is visible

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a horizontal only, full screen activity in my android app. In this activity, I need to disable full screen keyboard in some `EditText` elements so that the user can see the `EditText` while typing.

I disabled the full screen keyboard by adding following to `EditText` xml.

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

When I touch the `EditText` for the fist time to enter text into it, the screen gets pulled up (keyboard comes up from bottom) so that `EditText` is visible while typing. After entering text and closing the keyboard, while the `EditText` is still having focus, if I touched it again to do some correction to the text entered, it doesn't get pulled up as it did before (Edit text is covered by keyboard). So I cannot see what is in the text box while typing. I'm not sure whether this is the default behavior since user has no idea what he is typing in this situation.

Is there a some way to get the screen to always pull up so it is visible?

Answer (score 0):

use edittext in ScrollView and `android:fillViewport="true"` on the ScrollView. That's the better solution.

Comment: I used a `ScrollView` as the outermost element and set `android:fillViewport="true"`. But there's no difference in the behavior

Comment: scrollview let edit text to flow over the keyboard, please try and check also in other devices.